# Webpage wrongfully reloads on javascript close

Tags: javascript, php, html, reload

Trying to create a webpage with a dynamic selection of model numbers based on the selection of a manufacturer, using just php mysql queries (i.e. no jQuery or AJAX). The user would select a manufacturer, a form would submit, and the webpage would reload with all user inputs and a newly populated selection field for model numbers.

I have 2 forms, a main visible one where all inputs are required for my mysql database, and a hidden one that can be submitted with partial inputs. The only purpose of the hidden one is to submit the manufacturer and maintain all other inputs the user has provided on the page.

```
<form id="partialnew" action="page.php" method="post">
    <input id="partialnewmodel" name="partialnewmodel" type="hidden">
    ... other similar inputs ...
</form>

<form id="new" action="page.php" method="post">
    <select id="newmanufacturer" name="newmanufacturer" onchange=populatemodels() form="partialnew">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <?php
            ... populated from mysql query ...
        ?>
    </select>

    <select id="newmodel" name="newmodel" required>
    </select>
    ... other inputs ...
</form>
```

The manufacturer input is in the main form so it appears correctly on the page, but it is linked to the partial form so it can be submitted without the other required inputs.

OnChange of the manufacturer, I copy all my main form inputs to the hidden form, and call form.submit() on that partial form. When the page reloads, I query my database for model numbers based on the selected manufacturer. Then I load the maintained values into javascript using echo.

```
echo "<script>
        var manufacturer = '';
        var model = '';
        ... other variables ...
";

if (isset($_POST['newmanufacturer']) && $_POST['newmanufacturer'])
{
    echo "manufacturer = '{$_POST['newmanufacturer']}';";
}

if (isset($_POST['partialnewmodel']) && $_POST['partialnewmodel'])
{
    echo "model = '{$_POST['partialnewmodel']}';";
}

... load other inputs into javascript ...

echo "</script>";    // <--- After this command, the webpage reloads
```

I don't know why, but after the script is closed with that last echo, the page reloads.
I have added print statements and console logs before and after that echo, and it only returns those before.
I have tried adding a window.stop() command to prevent it from immediately reloading, but it didn't look like anything was amiss when I inspected the resulting webpage.

When it reloads, it purges all of my posted inputs and returns the webpage to its default state.

**EDIT** I just moved my php code to a different file, and pointed the hidden form action to the new file. Here is the entire new file.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Muh Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.svg" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $_POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

        $mysqli = new mysqli('**********', '**********', '**********', '**********');

        if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
            die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
        }

        if (empty($_POST))
        {
            echo "<p>POST is empty</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
                echo "<p>" . $key . " - " . $value . "</p>";
            }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['newmanufacturer']))
        {
            echo "<p>start of newmanufacturer handling</p>";
            $sql = "SELECT Model
                    FROM Models
                    WHERE ManufacturerName='{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['newmanufacturer'])}'
                    ORDER BY Model;";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

            if ($result)
            {
                $models = array();
                $i = 0;

                while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
                {
                    $models[$i] = $row['Model'];
                    $i = $i + 1;
                }

                $_SESSION['Model'] = $models;
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<p style="color: red;">ERROR ' . $mysqli->errno . ': MySQL error description=' . $mysqli->error . '</p>';
            }

            echo "<p>before scripting in newmanufacturer handling</p>";

            echo "<script>
                var location = '';
                var description = '';
                var manufacturer = '';
                var model = '';
                var serialnumber = '';
                var additionalinfo = '';
            ";
            if (isset($_POST['partialnewlocation']) && $_POST['partialnewlocation'])
            {
                echo "location = '{$_POST['partialnewlocation']}';";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['partialnewdescription']) && $_POST['partialnewdescription'])
            {
                echo "description = '{$_POST['partialnewdescription']}';";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['newmanufacturer']) && $_POST['newmanufacturer'])
            {
                echo "console.log('manufacturer loading into js');";
                echo "manufacturer = '{$_POST['newmanufacturer']}';";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['partialnewmodel']) && $_POST['partialnewmodel'])
            {
                echo "console.log('model loading into js');";
                echo "model = '{$_POST['partialnewmodel']}';";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['partialnewserialnumber']) && $_POST['partialnewserialnumber'])
            {
                echo "serialnumber = '{$_POST['partialnewserialnumber']}';";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['partialnewadditionalinfo']) && $_POST['partialnewadditionalinfo'])
            {
                echo "additionalinfo = '{$_POST['partialnewadditionalinfo']}';";
            }
            echo "console.log('done loading into js');";
            // echo "window.stop();";
            echo "</script>";
            
            echo "<script>
                console.log('never reach here');
                window.stop(); 
            </script>";
            echo "<p>Never reach here neither</p>";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This new file has the same problem. Unless I uncomment the window.stop() line, it will immediately reload. There is nothing else at all in this file.

Comment: what does `populatemodels` do? What does the response look like without the php code?

Comment: populatemodels is literally just a straight copy from one form to another.

document.getElementById("partialnewmodel").value = document.getElementById("newmodel").value;
... repeat for all inputs that are not the manufacturer ...
document.forms['partialnew'].submit();

Comment: `.submit()` submits the form to your server, which will typically result in a new page being loaded.

Comment: I know. That is the initial and expected reload that I described as "When the page reloads, I query my database for model numbers based on the selected manufacturer".

The page reloads again after I load the posted inputs into javascript. This second reload is the problem, and occurs automatically without touching anything

Comment: It is hard for us to guess what the issue is. On page submit the form vaules that you had set originally will go away as the new page loads. The new code runs..... we have not idea what is in the new code. So I would say start out by commenting out a lot of code and slowly add it back in until you find the smoking gun.

Comment: I've provided all of the javascript code, and have only removed the references to other variables that have no special behavior.

As for php, I've tracked the code with print statements myself to know that it never passes the `echo "</script>";` line, nor calls any other javascript functions.

I will try removing code again, but that did not help me the first time

Comment: PHP does not "call JavaScript functions" as you've put it in your comment above. It merely echoes content to the browser - that content may be HTML, JavaScript, CSS or anything else. Have you somewhere in the PHP sent a redirect header, or echoed a meta refresh tag, or output some extra JavaScript which causes another form submission or other navigation action? Also, have you tried using the browser's JavaScript debugger to see what JS code (if any) is executed as soon as the page is loaded?

Comment: @ADyson understood with regards to calling javascript functions.

I am not familiar with redirection headers nor meta refresh tags. My PHP is POST checking, MySQL queries, and loading values into javascript. I have checked for other form submissions, but I haven't been able to find any. I am not calling submit() on any other form, and all the rest of my submissions are by buttons only.

I have tried using the debugger, but the webpage reloads immediately. If I use window.stop() before the `echo "</script>"` the debugger returns _Error: Incorrect contents fetched, please reload_.

Comment: I would even take it a step further.  If you’re doing a refresh of the page with every submission instead of using ajax, two forms complicate things unnecessarily. Fixing that might very well take care of the current issue. You should be able to either fill in the default value or mark the selected option when you generate the refreshed page. Adding to that, these should be `GET` for reading; `POST` is for changing stored data. As you currently have it, if a user hits the back button things will get messy... and very annoying to the user.

Comment: @TimMorton I have two forms because I'm using my main form to require all necessary values for my mysql queries. I could handle that at POST, but I don't think it's as clean for the user to be allowed to submit the form when I won't accept their input.

I am familiar with setting the default value/selecting an option. If my page ever got past this error, I'd do so as the very next thing.

You are probably right about changing it to `GET` though. I'm new to HTML and have been using `POST` for everything, but `GET` does seem more appropriate for the partial form

Comment: I think the two form thing is over-complicating it as well. One form could do the job, but just hide all the other fields (and don't validate or process them on the server) until a manufacturer is selected. But anyway, we're having a hard time helping you because you keep saying there isn't anything that could trigger this issue, without actually proving it, and the evidence of executing the code is that isn't really the case

Comment: P.s. any reason you don't just use AJAX to populate the model numbers? It would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @ADyson I just extracted the entire PHP section that is run and reloads the page to a second file, and redirected my hidden form action to post to the new file. I provided the file as an edit. You now have the entire file of code that is run, so far as I know.

I don't connect my development environment to the internet, so downloading and installing modules like jQuery is a pain. If I can't find a solution to my problem, I may end up having to use jQuery, but it's not my first choice and this problem is...strange.

Comment: You don't need jQuery to make Ajax requests though, so I'm not sure how that's relevant (I assume you're referring to my earlier remark about using AJAX to populate the model numbers.)

Comment: P.S. as an aside, you could make all that checking of POST variables and setting of JS variables a lot more efficient and less verbose by just creating a PHP object and encoding it to JSON, and using that as an object literal in the JS.

Comment: So...you're saying when that page loads, the last thing you see if `done loading into js` in the console? And then it reloads? Does it reload the exact same page again? Is the refresh a GET or a POST? If you set your developer tools preserve the network log and console in between requests, you might be able to see what triggered the browser to do the reload

Comment: @ADyson Yes, the last console log is `done loading into js`.
The last php echo is `<p>before scripting in newmanufacturer handling</p>`.

When it reloads, it returns to the same page (my new file, test.php) but without any of my POST info.

Checking the network log, there is a POST to test.php from my original file where I would expect (.submit() call in javascript).
Then there is a GET from test.php to test.php at line 12, the first line of my javascript `var location='';`.
Lastly a GET of my favicon.svg

Comment: `var location='';`...of course. That's it. `location` is an alias of `window.location`. And I'm hopeful you don't need me to tell you what that does. Proof of concept: https://jsfiddle.net/k4tanxd2/. You'd have to name the variable something else, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/k4tanxd2/2/ . (P.S. If you follow my suggestion anyway to put all this stuff into a single object (which you can easily use PHP to create via json_encode) then this wouldn't arise anyway. Or just use AJAX instead of 2 forms, as per an earlier suggestion, so you don't need any of the re-population code to begin with.

Comment: @ADyson that did it. Leave an answer and I'll accept it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var location='';
```

is the problem. Because it's not inside a function or otherwise scoped, this is effectively an alias for `window.location` (since `window` is the default object in browser-based JS). And setting that value is an instruction to the browser to navigate to the page specified in that value. (If you set an empty string as in this example, it will navigate to the current URL again.)

Here's a proof of concept showing this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/k4tanxd2/

You just need to name the variable something else, e.g.:

```
var loc = '';
```

(Or of course you can take a different design approach which doesn't involve creating lots of global variables.)